# What is the best practice to create users via API?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, architecture, odoo, software-design

I am building a mobile app which uses users and the Odoo backend.
The user should be able to create a user account via this mobile app.
I can connect with the API and create a user but I am concerned about security issues.

If the user already has an account, he should connect to the backend using his credentials (login and password). If not, he should be able to create an account.

Currently the user is allowed to create new users and I can do that via API, with a "global" user, which I use to connect to the backend and create the real user account. After connecting to the backend, he is given a session_id. Then he can create a new user. Afterwards, the new user is able to login with his own credentials and consume other services.

What is the best practice to use in this case?

Should I create a token or something to ensure the App is being accessed via device or to avoid possible hacker attacks e.g. creating a bunch of fake users, by discovering the database name, server and password, by faking the App use? What should I implement to avoid this security issue?

Am I really threatened? Should I really be concerned or is it already ok?

This is most likely a Software Architecture question. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can add email verification for account to be activated, or "I'm not a robot captcha"...